# dplyr group_by returns blank

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following dimensions:

```
18549282 obs. of  3 variables:

$ road: chr  "MULTILINESTRING((30.5592664 -30.5971316,30.5597665 -30.5964615))" ...
$ n1       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ n2       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

There are no blank records in the road column, meaning that every record has a character.

When I use dplyr's group_by along with summarize to get the sum of n1 and sum of n2 by road I get a sum of n1 and n2 but I see a blank in the road column. e.g.

```
tt %>%
group_by(road) %>%
summarize(sn1 = sum(n1),
sn2 = sum(n2))
```

I get:

[image]

Again I'm 100% sure that there are no blanks in the road column.

But when I create a data frame with, lets say 1000 records as follows

```
small_dataset <- head(tt, 1000)
```

I don't see any blank records in the results:

[image]

Seems that dplyr strudels with the large amount of data.

Any ideas on how I can handle this issue?

Comment: `"I'm 100% sure that there are no blanks"`, how did you test this? What is the output of `sum(tt$road == "")` ?

Comment: Jip 100%, tested it a couple of times. I found a solution in rquery, see below. It produces no blanks in the results. Very strange. As soon as I have this project done I'll reinstall R and all the packages maybe an issue on my PC.

Comment: Could that be that dplyr is seeing "NULL" as blank and rquery ignores them?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, found a package I wasn't familiar with called [rquery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rquery/index.html).

```
tt  %>%
rquery::project(., 
count := n(),
 n1 := sum(n1),
n2 :=  sum(n2),
groupby = 'road')
```

solved my issue and it is faster than dplyr's group_by function.

Comment: So I reinstalled R and all the packages, and dplyr now works 100%. Very strange.